# How to improve performance of .loc appending the dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, append

I'm struggling with one problem.

Main idea is to improve performance of this kind of appending:

```
df.loc[some_list,column_name] = df.loc[some_list,column_name] + some_string
```

As it appends multiple values at once in specific places  (described by the some_list list) I can't use .at or .iat. Is there any way to improve the performance in that kind of appending or the structure of the code should be changed?

Comment: Do not use the + operator. Use a list and join at the end to avoid a quadratic complexity.

Comment: Please, tell us about some string. This is a list of strings or a constant string? Can you show a part of a dataframe? And an output you want.

Comment: @Alexey some_string is a string like f"-{custom_name}" and the whole append is in for loop.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Okay. I get it. So I should split the .loc append and it will improve the performance?